# Appropriate test for categorical independent variables with sub-level

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, ancova

I am stuck on how to analyse my data. I have one dependent variable and a number of indepen dent variables which are divided into further sub-categories. Some of the options for the value of an independent variable have other sub-levels than others. Concretely, my variables are organised as follows:

| var name | levels | sub-levels | sub-sub levels | sub-sub-sub levels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| post-processing | no |  |  |  |
|  | yes | author grouping | ignore |  |
|  |  |  | one |  |
|  |  |  | multiple |  |
|  |  | document grouping |  |  |
| augmentation | no |  |  |  |
|  | yes | fraction 0.7 |  |  |
|  |  | fraction 0.5 |  |  |
| validation | A |  |  |  |
|  | B |  |  |  |
| feature selection | no |  |  |  |
|  | yes | method1 | 10 | a |
|  |  |  | 10 | b |
|  |  |  | 10 | c |
|  |  |  | 15 | a |
|  |  |  | 15 | b |
|  |  |  | 15 | c |
|  |  |  | 20 | a |
|  |  |  | 20 | b |
|  |  |  | 20 | c |
|  |  | method 2 | 10 | a |
|  |  |  | 10 | b |
|  |  |  | 10 | c |
|  |  |  | 15 | a |
|  |  |  | 15 | b |
|  |  |  | 15 | c |
|  |  |  | 20 | a |
|  |  |  | 20 | b |
|  |  |  | 20 | c |

I've ran experiments with every possible combination of levels, and now I want to analyze which factors are important. However, I'm unsure how to deal with the fact that for example `post-processing: no` can occur, and `post-processing:yes, author grouping, ignore`, can occur but not for example `post-processing: no, author grouping` or `post-processing: yes, document grouping, ignore`.

I was thinking of concatenating some factors, so then I'd get things like `post-processing: no` versus `post-processing: yes_author_grouping_ignore` versus `post-processing: yes_author_grouping_one` but then I don't know how to extract back out the effect of e.g. `ignore` versus `one`.

Any help is much appreciated as are any questions if I need to clarify further!

Comment: How would you "analyze which factors are important" in a more straightforward setting?

Comment: @Dave From what I've seen, Multi-way ANOVA, ANCOVA, or Multilinear Regression, depending on how I treat the continuous variables, seem most suitable?